# how to add comment when adding column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to write a PostgreSQL script that can be executed repeatedly.

I want to add a column for my table, and check if the table and column exist, and add comment.

So I write this:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_user ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS age INT COMMENT 'age';
```

but I got an error . It seems that "COMMENT" is not allowed here.

Is there a way to add comment in one statement when adding column?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) `comment on` is a separate statement.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to add the comment in a separate statement:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_user ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS age INT;

COMMENT ON COLUMN tbl_user.age IS 'age';
```

Comment: if you need both to happen at the exact same time you can run them inside a transaction.